# Cant fix this: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

Im tried to reprogram it several times and i have already followed all the answers here but Im not able to fix this error! 
I really dont know what else I have to change in order to fix it, im not so good in this.

```
<?php
$realname = $_POST ["nombreyapellido"];
$nick = $_POST ["correoelectronico"];
$contrasena = $_POST ["pass"];
$reqlen = strlen ($realname) * strlen ($nick) * strlen ($contrasena);

if($reqlen > 0) {
if ($realname === $nick) {


require ("connect_db.php");
mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO Tutorial VALUES ('','$realname','$nick', 'contrasena')");

mysqli_close ($link);


} else { 
echo "Por favor, introduzca dos correos idénticos" ;

}

} else {
echo "Por favor, rellene todos los campos requeridos.";

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget 1 argument in `mysqli_query`:
`mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

It should be: `mysqli_query ($link, "INSERT INTO Tutorial VALUES ('','$realname','$nick', 'contrasena')");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the procedural style call to `mysqli_query`, which expects two parameters: a link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` or `mysqli_init()` and a query. You are using only a query.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is your friend.